# ElasticSearch: How to update a specific value in index

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to update a specific value from the index in elasticsearch. For example if i have 2 objects(like in the image): one with tags = "blue" and another with tags = "red", how can i do in order to update only the tag with red value?

[values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EosOC.png)

Comment: Need some more clarifications here, you want to update all the records with tag="red" or only the record with tag="red" and id="8vCyZ2YBcNKIHEcDP-k"

Comment: All the records with tags=red

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the update_by_query API with a script. You can find the ugly details here: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html